# Android: Media is not Accessing after uploading to private bucket using AWS

Tags: android, amazon-s3, media, amazon-cognito

Bucket which is created on AWS is private.
I am not able to access the file when uploading with private access mode.
Uploading successfully when uploading media using below method.

Bucket Name with URL getting from util class

```
    String bucketName = Util.getBucketNameFromUrl(uploadPath);
    String fileNameIncludingSubFolders = localPath.substring(localPath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    Uri mUri = Uri.parse(localPath);
```

File for uploading to AWS

```
File mFile = new File(mUri.toString().trim());

        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(  Ut.getCredentialsCognito(context));
        PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileNameIncludingSubFolders, mFile);
        por.setProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {

            @Override
            public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent prgEvent) {
                if (progressUpdate != null) {
                    progressUpdate.progressStatus(String.valueOf(prgEvent.getBytesTransferred()));
                }
            }
        });
```

Access mode is Private when Uploading media file

```
        try {
            por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.Private);
            s3Client.putObject(por);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What's the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

All you are doing is fine. Upload will be working good.
Only thing you require is to generate signed URL.
Use AWS SDK `GeneratePresignedUrlRequest` for this. This class have many methods, you can also set expiry date for the link and other stuff.

```
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("ACCESS_KEY_ID", "SECRET_KEY_ID");
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials );
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest request = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, fileKey);
URL objectURL = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(request);
```

You can find the file key and key name as following:
 `https://s3-[region]..amazonaws.com/[bucket name]/[file key]`